# Issue testing admob in my phone

Tags: android, admob

I created an application, I want to test the code Admob I used the following code but it does not work

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: please upload logs in your question as well

Comment: Did you also add the Java or Kotlin code that will load an ad into the AdView? https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner